# Name for pre-supergiant main sequence stars

Tags: main-sequence

The massive main-sequence stars which turn into supergiants--do they typically have special terminology for their classifications as do the less massive ones (which may be, e.g., "yellow dwarf" or "red dwarf")? Just "non-dwarf main sequence" or?

(I'm quite a novice, so pardon me if my premises are wrong too. Just trying to get a sense of some of the broad categories.)